# Laptop sleep mode not working in windows and linux?

Tags: linux, windows, boot, laptop, sleep

I have ASUS N550JK laptop with nVidia 850M GPU, 1TB HDD (Caddy Drive) & 250 Samsung 850 Evo SSD.

Since last week, whenever I resume my laptop from sleep, it starts like I have turned on my PC from shutdown. All my opened applications are closed and everything reloads from the start.

The strange thing is, when I put my laptop to sleep mode, the status led blinks normally as if the laptop is in sleep mode and this phenomena is present in both of my installed OS.

I have dual OS installed; 
 1. Windows 10 X64 & 
 2. Manjaro KDE Plasma 19.

Here's what I've tried:

1. Disable Secure Boot & Fast Boot from BIOS settings (tried all combinations)
2. Turned On/Off Fast boot from windows power settings
3. Turned On/Off hybrid sleep from windows power settings
4. Turned On/Off windows hibernation
5. Deleted all UEFI Partitions and Re-installing UEFI for Windows
6. Windows Start up repairs, checkdsk & sfc /scannow
7. Uninstalled Windows 10 and installed windows 8.1 with only company provided drivers and re-trying all 
   of the above
8. Tried sleeping laptop in plugged in/out state

> UPDATE: 9. Ran complete RAM test, no errors founds.

I am now totally clueless where the fault is and what I should do to make sleep work as it should?

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/106772/discussion-on-question-by-hquser-laptop-sleep-mode-not-working-in-windows-and-li).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reverting BIOS to the last released version fixed the problem. All it seemed like the new BIOS update was somehow conflicting with the latest windows codebase and updates.

It was really strange that the new BIOS update used to work fine for quite a long time. In new BIOS update, when I used to put the computer to the sleep, and upon resuming up, the computer had started just like it was cold started but all of my opened programs were there and the whole session was saved, however, now that I reverted to last BIOS update, the computer wakes up directly from the login screen instead of acting like waking up from a cold start.

UPDATE: After upgrading to the newest version of Windows 10 (Build 2004 aka May Update 2020), the same issue reappeared. It seems like windows update is somehow changing the BIOS programming of this notebook leading to sleep issues. I reflashed the same BIOS update which was previously causing the problem and the issue is again resolved.